# Network Group with VMware between Windows 10 and Windows 7 possible?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, network-shares, home-networking, vmware

I want to simulate a company Network.

I have a computer running Windows 10 Pro.

On this computer, I have installed VMware, and I have set up a Windows 7 machine in it.

I would now like to simulate a company Network.

I would like to be able to map drives.

With the homegroup gone in the last Windows 10 update, I'm unsure if that is possible at all.

Thank you for any Response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loss of Homegroup won't prevent you from sharing files/mapping drives, and to be honest had you used Homegroup to do so it wouldn't have been much of a simulation of a company network anyway - as the name implied it wasn't something that was ever really intended for  business use and other than really, really tiny companies I doubt it was used much in a work context.

So to answer your main question if you want to share a file/folder in Win10 now here's how you do it:

1. Select your chosen file/folder and right click on it
2. Select "Give access to"
3. Select "Specific People"
4. Select the appropriate user you want to share with in the drop down and click "Add"
5. Repeat Step 4 for any more users you want to have access.
6. Click "Share" when done.
7. You'll see a summary of the item(s) shared and the UNC path to them.
8. Click "Done".

If you want to access the share from the Win7 VM you'll just need to do the following:

1. Click "Start"
2. Click "Run"
3. Type the UNC path of the share into the Run dialog e.g: \\win10machinename\sharedfolder\ and click run.
4. If logged into the Win7 machine as a different user to the one you gave access to you'll be prompted for credentials.

If you want to map the network drive to the share do:

1. Click "Start"
2. Click "Run"
3. Type the UNC path of the Win10 machine into the Run dialog e.g: \\win10machinename\
4. Right-click on the share name and select "Map Network Drive"
5. Give the network  drive a  drive letter and click "Ok"

And that should be all you need. It is worth mentioning however that this is still not a particularly accurate simulation of a company network - most companies will operate an Active Directory setup up and if you're looking to explore more than simple sharing you'll want to look into doing that instead. If you want to go down that route you'll need a copy of Windows Server (you could always download a 180 day trial of Server 2016 to experiment with) but setting that up is outside the scope of this question so I won't go on about that now.

Comment: @AntonioC Happy to help! Just edited as I realised I'd missed some backslashes in my example paths (UNC paths begin with a double \ and SE had escaped one of them!)